# SimCash Purchase

Tags: simcity-buildit

I purchased SimCash when I started to build. I now understand that when you do that you don't get ad videos or prizes from those videos. If I continue to purchase it, do I lose anything else? Like popups with free items? Can I get the ad videos back?

Comment: You're asking for how to get *more* ads?

Comment: I liked them because you got free goods.

Comment: I guess I'm more worried if I purchase additional green money will I lose something else? Do they just not want you to purchase...is that cheating?

Comment: I'm not sure how SimCity Buildit works, but from experience with other games with microtransactions, usually ads show up less for users who pay real money. Words with Friends straight up allows players to spend X dollars to completely remove ads from their games. The whole purpose of the ads is to make money from users who don't spend their own money on the game. EA most likely *wants* you to spend more money on the game, so they aren't going to throw as many ads your way. That's just my guess.

Comment: Ads disappeared entirely once I purchased. I would think they would want you to spend as well. At the end of the ad .. you pick a box and get a "prize" item so not getting those....though I don't miss the ads themselves. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get the ads back at some point (not sure), but you can always get SimCash with achievements and with the login chests! From what I have heard from other users, it’s most likely that you won’t be able to get ads back so that you will spend on more SimCash!

You won’t lose anything else if you purchase more SimCash, now that you have already purchased some.